# What is the word for two different sides against each other?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

Ok so you all know cowboys vs Indians, Russia vs USA, blue black vs white gold (the Internet dress)
Is there a word for two sides against each other? If you get what I am saying.

Comment: It would help of you gave an example sentence with a blank where your word fits.

Comment: I might as well need to drop by Google to find what those actually are - the references I mean!

Answer (score 1):

The word is *Opponents*, those who oppose one another. If they are like the pairs you suggest then they may be classic or prosaic opponents, eternal. In any case they are *Enemies* with too much of a history of hatred to kiss and make up any time soon.